# timer uses large amount of memory

Tags: java

For my MIDI player, I wanted to print 10 times in a second to get an accuracy of the timing but, the program consume quite a large amount of memory, how do I fix the code?

```
public void tick(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new tickcount(), seconds * 100);
}

class tickcount extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        if(sequencer != null) {
            System.out.println("sec"+sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition()/1000000);
            timer = null;
            tick(1);
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a different part of your program that consumes the memory. (and just as a side-note, you should try to use convention when naming classes, so tickcount should be TickCount).

Comment: sure, but you mean print out will use lot of memory? I just added the timer code.

Comment: how have you determined that this part of the code is consuming the memory?

Comment: as mentioned, I just add the timer code a moment ago vs without the timer code. It consumer about 50MB more.

Comment: Are you sure, a simple System.out.println does'n consume nearly as much memory? Java system classes are not the smallest, and the Java StartUp time/memory consumption has always been an issue.

Comment: erm, so what is your advice? I been testing quite a lot on MIDI application, the timer are quite aggressive on memory, not the print out as I been testing other similar program for months, is there any more code need to clean up?

Comment: This might be a shot in the dark, but System.out.println() is a buffered operation. If you use System.err.println() instead, it might make a difference as that is unbuffered output.

Comment: Nope, there was a mistake in my code but not everyone notice it... it the timer object being create instead of reused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really see how this code could be causing any kind of large memory consumption, unless it has to do with the incredible rate at which it'll be creating new threads.

At any rate, you should use a `ScheduledExecutorService`... `Timer` is kind of outdated (though even using it, you shouldn't be creating a new `Timer` each time your task runs). If you want the code in your `tickcount` task to run once every 0.1 seconds, you could do it like this:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

private Future<?> timingTask;

public void tick(long milliseconds) {
  timingTask = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("sec"+sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition()/1000000);
    }
  }, 0, milliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Here, the `tick` method will start your timer running, calling the `Runnable` every `milliseconds` ms, starting immediately. It also assigns a `Future<?>` to a field... this allows you to call `timingTask.cancel(true)` to cancel the scheduled task from running prior to setting `sequencer` to `null`.

Comment: [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is an interface representing the (future) result of a task that may or may not have run yet. Technically, the `schedule` methods in a `ScheduledExecutorService` return a `ScheduledFuture`, but the important thing here is the `cancel` method on `Future` which allows you to cancel the running task when you need to.

Comment: Yes, manage to get it work. Thank you for providing useful technique, it would be great for others to learn too.

Answer (score 3):

Other than creating Timer object every time in tick() method call use a global timer object instance and reuse it

Comment: move the timer = new Timer(); to the top?